# Timeout caused potentially by curl_setopt | PHP

Tags: php, curl

Essentially the following script is working fine when in local host but fails to load (Timeout) anytime loaded from a web server, is their something incorrectly written? I know it's not the end point api url that's the issue, since it works on local. Please see below, wondering if it's caused by curl_setopt:

```
    $id = "dhl";
    $number = "039103913";


    // Parameters setting
    $key = 'key';
    $secret = 'scret';
    $param = array (
        'id' => $id,
        'number' => $number,
        'phone' => '',
        'ship_from' => '',
        'ship_to' => '',
        'area_show' => 1,
        'order' => 'desc'                    
    );
    
    // Request Json
    $json = json_encode($param, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    $signature = strtoupper(md5($json.$key.$secret));
    
    $url = 'https://www.kd100.com/api/v1/tracking/realtime';

    $headers = array (
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'API-Key:'.$key,
        'signature:'.$signature,
      'Content-Length:'.strlen($json)
    );

    // Send post request
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Which option do you think is causing it?

Comment: If you think one of the `curl_setopt()` is causing the problem, try removing each of them until the problem goes away. But none of them look too unusual, so I doubt that's the problem. A timeout is usually caused by something blocking the connection, check your firewall.